# Prove: $\operatorname{ord}(a)=\operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})$

Tags: group-theory

We have to look at to cases:

1. $n<\infty$
2. $n=\infty$

In the first case: let assume $\operatorname{ord}(a)=n$. Therefore:
$$e=(a^{-1}a)^n=a^na^{-n}=a^{-n}$$

So $\operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})\leq n$

In the second case: let assume $\operatorname{ord}(a)=\infty$ and $\operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})<\infty$ from the first case we know that $\operatorname{ord}(a)=\operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})<\infty$ contradiction.

How can I show the direction $n\leq \operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})$?

Comment: if $e = a^{-k}$ for some $k < n$ then by multiplying by $a^k$ we have $a^k = a^ka^{-k} = e$ so $\text{ord}(a) \le k < n$, contradicting $n = \text{ord}(a)$

Comment: You have shown that $ord(x^{-1})\leq ord(x)$. Well, this is true for any element, including $a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, we have:

- $\operatorname{ord}(a)=|\langle a \rangle$|
- $\langle a \rangle = \{ a^n : n \in \mathbb Z \}$
- $\langle a \rangle = \langle a^{-1} \rangle$

Thus, $\operatorname{ord}(a)=|\langle a \rangle| = |\langle a^{-1} \rangle| = \operatorname{ord}(a^{-1})$.

In words: the two sets are either both infinite or both finite of the same size.

Answer (score 1):

In the finite case: Suppose $a^n=e$, and is the smallest positive integer for which this is true. Then, by definition, $n={\rm ord}(a)$.

> Lemma: If $a^k=e$, then $k=mn$, where $m$ is an integer.

Proof: Suppose there is a $k$ for which this is not true (the general form is of the form $k=mn+r$, where $r$ is some remainder in the range $0\le r<n$). In that case, one can multiply by the identity in the form of $a^n$ or $a^{-n}$, meaning you can generate a new $k$ that is either $k+n$, or $k-n$ (so $m$ is raised or lowered by one, $r$ is unchanged). Repeat until you have a $k$ in the range $0\le k<n$. If $k$ is not equal to $0$, this contradicts our assertion that $n$ is the smallest positive integer for which $a^k=e$. Therefore, $r=0$, and $k=mn$.$\square$

It is now easy to show that the $(a^{-1})^k=a^{-k}$ will equal the identity exactly when $k$ is a multiple of $n$, by our earlier lemma, and that $n$ is the smallest positive value for which this will be true, making it ${\rm ord}(a^{-1})$.